# F# MailboxProcessor - multiple waiting reader continuations for mailbox

Tags: exception, f#, parallel-processing, mailboxprocessor

Im playing around with writing something like a really simple asynchronous testing framework.
But I think I'm hitting some kind of limitation or bug. Sorry but I was not able to reproduce this on a smaller codebase.

This is the basic Framework I came up with:

```
module TestRunner
    open System

    type TestOptions = {
        Writer : ConsoleColor -> string -> unit}
    type TestResults = {
        Time : TimeSpan
        Failure : exn option
        }
    type Test = {
        Name : string
        Finished : IEvent<TestResults>
        SetFinished : TestResults -> unit
        TestFunc : TestOptions -> Async<TestResults> }

    let createTest name f =  
        let ev = new Event<TestResults>()
        {
            Name = name 
            Finished = ev.Publish
            SetFinished = (fun res -> ev.Trigger res)
            TestFunc = 
                (fun options -> async {
                    let watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
                    try
                        do! f options
                        watch.Stop()
                        return { Failure = None; Time = watch.Elapsed }
                    with exn ->
                        watch.Stop()
                        return { Failure = Some exn; Time = watch.Elapsed }
                    })}

    let simpleTest name f = 
        createTest name (fun options -> f options.Writer)

    /// Create a new Test and change the result
    let mapResult mapping test = 
        { test with
            TestFunc = 
                (fun options -> async {
                    let! result = test.TestFunc options
                    return mapping result})}

    let writeConsole color f = 
        let old = System.Console.ForegroundColor
        try
            System.Console.ForegroundColor <- color
            f()
        finally
            System.Console.ForegroundColor <- old

    let printColor color (text:String) = 
        writeConsole color (fun _ -> Console.WriteLine(text))


    type WriterMessage = 
        | NormalWrite of ConsoleColor * String
        | StartTask of AsyncReplyChannel<int> * String
        | WriteMessage of int * ConsoleColor * String
        | EndTask of int

    /// will handle printing jobs for two reasons
    /// 1. Nice output grouped by tests (StartTask,WriteMessage,EndTask)
    /// 2. Print Summary after all tests finished (NormalWrite)
    let writer = MailboxProcessor.Start (fun inbox -> 
        let currentTask = ref 0
        let newHandle (returnHandle:AsyncReplyChannel<int>) = 
            let handle = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment currentTask
            returnHandle.Reply handle
            handle 

        // the tasks describe which tasks are currently waiting to be processed
        let rec loop tasks = async {
            let! newTasks =
                match tasks with
                /// We process the Task with the number t and the name name
                | (t, name) :: next -> 
                    inbox.Scan
                        (fun msg -> 
                            match msg with
                            | EndTask (endTask) -> 
                                // if the message is from the current task finish it
                                if t = endTask then
                                    Some (async { return next })
                                else None
                            | WriteMessage(writeTask, color, message) ->
                                if writeTask = t then 
                                    Some (async {
                                        printColor color (sprintf "Task %s: %s" name message)
                                        return tasks
                                    })
                                else None
                            | StartTask (returnHandle, name) -> 
                                // Start any tasks instantly and add them to the list (because otherwise they would just wait for the resonse)
                                Some (async { 
                                    let handle = newHandle returnHandle
                                    return (List.append tasks [handle, name]) })
                            | _ -> None)
                // No Current Tasks so just start ones or process the NormalWrite messages
                | [] ->
                    inbox.Scan     
                        (fun msg -> 
                            match msg with
                            | StartTask (returnHandle, name) -> 
                                Some (async { 
                                    let handle = newHandle returnHandle
                                    return [handle, name] })
                            | NormalWrite(color, message) ->
                                Some (async {
                                    printColor color message
                                    return []
                                })
                            | _ -> None)   

            return! loop newTasks 
        }
        loop [])

    /// Write a normal message via writer
    let writerWrite color (text:String) = 
        writer.Post(NormalWrite(color, text))

    /// A wrapper around the communication (to not miss EndTask for a StartTask)
    let createTestWriter name f = async {
        let! handle = writer.PostAndAsyncReply(fun reply -> StartTask(reply, name))
        try
            let writer color s = 
                writer.Post(WriteMessage(handle,color,s))
            return! f(writer)
        finally
            writer.Post (EndTask(handle))
        }
    /// Run the given test and print the results
    let testRun t = async {
        let! results = createTestWriter t.Name (fun writer -> async {
            writer ConsoleColor.Green (sprintf "started")
            let! results = t.TestFunc { Writer = writer }
            match results.Failure with
            | Some exn -> 
                writer ConsoleColor.Red (sprintf "failed with %O" exn)
            | None ->
                writer ConsoleColor.Green (sprintf "succeeded!")
            return results}) 
        t.SetFinished results
        }
    /// Start the given task with the given amount of workers
    let startParallelMailbox workerNum f = 
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
            let workers = Array.init workerNum (fun _ -> MailboxProcessor.Start f)
            let rec loop currentNum = async {
                let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                workers.[currentNum].Post msg
                return! loop ((currentNum + 1) % workerNum)
            }
            loop 0 )
    /// Runs all posted Tasks
    let testRunner = 
        startParallelMailbox 10 (fun inbox ->
            let rec loop () = async {
                let! test = inbox.Receive()
                do! testRun test
                return! loop()
            }
            loop ())
    /// Start the given tests and print a sumary at the end
    let startTests tests = async {
        let! results =
            tests 
                |> Seq.map (fun t ->
                    let waiter = t.Finished |> Async.AwaitEvent
                    testRunner.Post t
                    waiter
                   )
                |> Async.Parallel
        let testTime = 
            results
                |> Seq.map (fun res -> res.Time)
                |> Seq.fold (fun state item -> state + item) TimeSpan.Zero
        let failed = 
            results
                |> Seq.map (fun res -> res.Failure) 
                |> Seq.filter (fun o -> o.IsSome)
                |> Seq.length
        let testCount = results.Length
        if failed > 0 then
            writerWrite ConsoleColor.DarkRed (sprintf "--- %d of %d TESTS FAILED (%A) ---" failed testCount testTime)
        else
            writerWrite ConsoleColor.DarkGray (sprintf "--- %d TESTS FINISHED SUCCESFULLY (%A) ---" testCount testTime)
        }
```

Now the Exception is only triggered when i use a specific set of tests
which do some crawling on the web (some fail and some don't which is fine):

```
#r @"Yaaf.GameMediaManager.Primitives.dll";; // See below
open TestRunner

let testLink link =
    Yaaf.GameMediaManager.EslGrabber.getMatchMembers link
    |> Async.Ignore

let tests = [
    // Some working links (links that should work)
    yield! 
      [ //"TestMatch", "http://www.esl.eu/eu/wire/anti-cheat/css/anticheat_test/match/26077222/"
        "MatchwithCheater", "http://www.esl.eu/de/csgo/ui/versus/match/3035028"
        "DeletedAccount", "http://www.esl.eu/de/css/ui/versus/match/2852106" 
        "CS1.6", "http://www.esl.eu/de/cs/ui/versus/match/2997440" 
        "2on2Versus", "http://www.esl.eu/de/css/ui/versus/match/3012767" 
        "SC2cup1on1", "http://www.esl.eu/eu/sc2/go4sc2/cup230/match/26964055/"
        "CSGO2on2Cup", "http://www.esl.eu/de/csgo/cups/2on2/season_08/match/26854846/"
        "CSSAwpCup", "http://www.esl.eu/eu/css/cups/2on2/awp_cup_11/match/26811005/"
        ] |> Seq.map (fun (name, workingLink) -> simpleTest (sprintf "TestEslMatches_%s" name) (fun o -> testLink workingLink))
    ]

startTests tests |> Async.Start;; // this will produce the Exception now and then
```

https://github.com/matthid/Yaaf.GameMediaManager/blob/core/src/Yaaf.GameMediaManager.Primitives/EslGrabber.fs is the code and you can download https://github.com/downloads/matthid/Yaaf.GameMediaManager/GameMediaManager.%200.9.3.1.wireplugin (this is basically a renamed zip archive) and extract it to get the Yaaf.GameMediaManager.Primitives.dll binary
(you can paste it into FSI instead of downloading when you want but then you have to reference the HtmlAgilityPack)

I can reproduce this with Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive, Build 4.0.40219.1. The Problem is that the Exception will not be triggered always (but very often) and the stacktrace is telling me nothing

```
System.Exception: multiple waiting reader continuations for mailbox
   bei <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control.-ctor@1860-3.Invoke(AsyncParams`1 _arg11)
   bei <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control.loop@413-40(Trampoline this, FSharpFunc`2 action)
   bei Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.ExecuteAction(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction)
   bei Microsoft.FSharp.Control.TrampolineHolder.Protect(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction)
   bei <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control.finishTask@1280[T](AsyncParams`1 _arg3, AsyncParamsAux aux, FSharpRef`1 firstExn, T[] results, TrampolineHolder trampolineHolder, Int32 remaining)
   bei <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control.recordFailure@1302[T](AsyncParams`1 _arg3, AsyncParamsAux aux, FSharpRef`1 count, FSharpRef`1 firstExn, T[] results, LinkedSubSource innerCTS, TrampolineHolder trampolineHolder, FSharpChoice`2 exn)
   bei <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control.Parallel@1322-3.Invoke(Exception exn)
   bei Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl.protectedPrimitive@690.Invoke(AsyncParams`1 args)
   bei <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control.loop@413-40(Trampoline this, FSharpFunc`2 action)
   bei Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.ExecuteAction(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction)
   bei Microsoft.FSharp.Control.TrampolineHolder.Protect(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction)
   bei <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control.-ctor@473-1.Invoke(Object state)
   bei System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   bei System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   bei System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   bei System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Because this is will be triggered on a worker thread, which I have no control of, this will crash the application (not FSI but the exception will be displayed here too).

I found http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/Some/2/59152 and http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/None/59146 but I do not use StartChild and I don't think I'm invoking Receive from multiple Threads at the same time somehow?

Is there anything wrong with my Code or is this indeed a bug? How can I workaround this if possible?

I noticed that in FSI that all tests will run as expected when the Exception is silently ignored. How can I do the same?

EDIT: I noticed after I fixed the failing unit tests it will work properly. However I can stil not reproduce this with a smaller codebase. For example with my own failing tests.

Thanks, matthid

Comment: Agents, agents...everywhere! That is some inscrutable code. Perhaps put a break point on every call to `Receive`/`Scan` and see if it breaks on the same thread every time.

Comment: It should actually break on different threads I guess. As I understand it the limitation is that only one Thread can call Receive (it can be called on different Threads but not at the same time?). That's the whole point of Async?
I will edit the code and add some comments.

Comment: I am using some code I wrote that implements an alternative to MailboxProcessor. I think it should work for you. Can you test it (I am too lazy to do that myself)? https://gist.github.com/3827112

Comment: There is no Scan implementation in it? So I have to implement my own (which I could do also on the MailboxProcessor) or do what 7sharp9 suggested?

Comment: @reddragon, no. I do not know of a way to efficiently implement it. Yea, I would try to do what 7sharp9 suggested, it might also declutter the code a bit. Could multiple channels work? I also would not use Events..

Comment: for example, something akin to https://gist.github.com/3834976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I never actually could reproduce this on a smaller code base, and now I would use NUnit with async test support instead of my own implementation. I used agents (MailboxProcessor) and asyncs in various projects since them and never encountered this again...

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is that the limitation would be within the MailboxProcessor itself rather than async.

To be honest I would err on the side of caution with the Scan functions.  I wrote a [blog post](http://moiraesoftware.com/blog/2012/07/15/the-lurking-horror/) on the dangers of using them.

Is it possible to process the tasks with the standard receiving mechanism rather than using Scan functions?

As a note, inside async there is trampoline that is used so that the same thread is reused a set number of time to avoid unnecessary thread pool usage, (I think this is set to 300) so when debugging you may see this behaviour.

I would approach this problem slightly differently decomposing the separate components into pipeline stages rather than the nested async blocks.  I would create a supervisor component and routing component.

The Supervisor would look after the initial tests and post messages to a routing component that would round-robin the requests to other agents.  When the tasks are completed they could post back to the supervisor.

I realise this does not really help with the problem in the current code but I think you will have to decompose the problem anyway in order to debug the async parts of the system.

Comment: You point out in your Blog-post the performance issue and that the timeout gets reset (or did I miss something?). None of those should really hurt in my scenario. I will try your suggestion with the supervisor, but I felt like Scan was the right thing to do in my scenario!

Comment: I just dont like the Scan implementation, I would rather re-architect an alternative than trust it.   I think you would benefit breaking the problem down further, It will make it easier to debug in any case.

Comment: As I understand it "Scan" is basically the Erlang way of actors. I have a custom implementation of the async builder which enables me to trace things very easy, however this seems to be out of my control. I also don't think this code is so "inscrutable" as everybody says (If you think about it from an higher level). Sadly I have not enough time to make a lot of changes at the moment but I will definitly look into this.

Comment: I have a blog post half written on the differences between Erlang/F# agents. Selective receive is the mechanism used in Erlang.  With selective receive the unmatched messages are kept to one side until a successful receive, at that point the unmatched messages are then moved back to the main buffer in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe there was a bug in the 2.0 implementation of `Scan`/`TryScan`/`Receive` that might spuriously cause the

```
multiple waiting reader continuations for mailbox
```

exception; I think that bug is now fixed in the 3.0 implementation.  I haven't looked carefully at your code to try to ensure you're only trying to receive one message at a time in your implementation, so it's also possible this might be a bug in your code.  If you can try it out against F# 3.0, it would be great to know if this goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I testet it with the F#3.0 Release (Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.50727.1) and the situation is actually worse. The Exception is triggered more often. However I have to stay on CLR2 (.net3.5) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes, in case someone finds my experiences useful (it took a long time debugging multiple processes in order to locate the problem):

Execution and throughput started to get clogged up with just 50 Agents/Mailboxes. Sometimes with a light load it would work for the first round of messages but anything as significant as making a call to a logging library triggered the longer delay.

Debugging using the Threads/Parallel Stacks window in the VS IDE, the runtime is waiting on the results of
FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously -> CancellationTokenOps.RunSynchronously call by Trampoline.ExecuteAction

I suspect that the underlying ThreadPool is throttling startup (after the first time it seems to run ok). It's a very long delay. I'm using agents to serialise within certain queues minor computations, while allowing the main dispatching agent to remain responsive, so the delay is somewhere in the CLR.

I found that running MailboxProcessor Receive with a Timeout within a try-with,  stopped the delay, but that this needed to be wrapped in an async block to stop the rest of the program slowing down, however short the delay. Despite a little bit of twiddling around, very happy with the F# MailboxProcessor for implementing the actor model.